# Java Spring deserialize object with @Value annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lombok

I have a class that represents request from front end to backend, and i want to annotate it with @Value so it can't be changed, but then I can't have NoArgsConstructor and when server is processing such request it fails with "cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)".
I tried to use "lombok.noArgsConstructor.extraPrivate=true" but providing default value for each entry in class is not what I want.
Is there any way to fix deserialization issue and keep @Value annotation instead of using @Data and @NoArgsConstructor?

Comment: you need to set the following property in your lombok.config file lombok.anyConstructor.addConstructorProperties=true

Comment: You could try `@Jacksonized @Builder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using combination of

```
@Value
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true, access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@AllArgsConstructor(staticName = "of")
```

because I create those requests in tests using static `of`